# Unable to run HLA application using Pitch RTI Free

Tags: c++, visual-c++, high-level-architecture

I have been trying to run an application using Visual Studio and Pitch RTI Free.  I have followed the instructions described in Ch 9 of the Pitch pRTI Users Guide. I have been attempting to use the chat-cc example shown included with the tutorial.  But whenever I try to run the program , I get an error:

> "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

[image: Error Popup]

I have tried this in both VS2019 and VS2010.  I have checked that all of the Visual C++ runtimes are installed and up to date as well as the .NET Framework Runtimes and I am at a loss.  I have looked at the Event Viewer and have found no information that seems pertinent to the underlying problem.

Update:
In investigating further, it seems that the problem is caused by the macro DEFINE_HANDLE_CLASS in Handle.h.  I found this by commenting out a majority of the code in ChatCC1516e.cpp to find out at what point the application would run.  There are a handful of declarations at the beginning of the ChatCCFederate that seem to be causing the problem.

Comment: Dan, are you able to run the pre-build binaries using the provided start scripts (.bat files)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the compiler you use is the same as the pRTI DLLs you are trying to load. You can confirm which DLL is being loaded by looking at the "Modules" pane within VS. The pRTI installer adds the DLLs for the latest VS version to the system path so yo have to be careful.

Also, if you have multiple RTIs (openrti, portico, MAK, etc) installed, maybe the sample is loading the incorrect DLL (since most HLA 1516e DLLs are named the same).